# Why file.delete() do not remove the resource from disk?

Tags: java, file, delete-file

My problem is, I need to delete all the files i.e. first, second, third. But as per below code only third file is getting deleted from path, not first and second. How to remove all files?

```
ArrayList<File> filesToAdd = new ArrayList<File>();
        filesToAdd.add(first);
        filesToAdd.add(second);
        filesToAdd.add(third);

for (File file : filesToAdd) {
  if(file!=null && file.isFile()){
   file.delete();
  }         
 }
```

Comment: 1) Aren't these files directories?
2) Do you have the correct privileges to delete these files?

Comment: Your code seems correct. The problem has to lurk somewhere else in code you did not post or lies in environmental conditions like write privileges.

Comment: Have you run it with a debugger ? Does the if-clause return true for the first two files ?

Comment: Don't ignore the boolean returned by delete(). And use Files.delete(Path) instead of File.delete() to get a meaningful exception explaining what the problem is, rather than a stupid boolean.

Comment: Are you aware that `File`'s `.delete()` silently fails? If using Java 7 or upper you should use java.nio.file instead

Answer (score 0):

when I run the app with debugger, if returns true for all files. 
And I can't pass file.delete(path) because path is String.

Answer (score -1):

The code you have try to delete files. There are few reasons why File.delete()

- you don't have correct permissions to delete
- the file the file represents a directory and the directory is not empty
- the file is locked by another process, (or even by the same process in say an unclosed FileOutputStream)
- the file doesn't exist

The method delete() return a boolean value that inform you about the state.

```
for (File file : filesToAdd) {
  if(file!=null && file.isFile()){
   if(file.delete() == false) {
     //Add code what should happen 
   }
  }         
 }
```

Note that your code is obsolete and use API from Java 6.

If it is possible switch to latest version 8, then you can

```
List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        paths.add(first);
        paths.add(second);
        paths.add(third);

for (Path path : paths) {
  if(Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
     Files.delete(path);
  }        
 }
```

The change is that `Files.delete(path)` will throw an exception that will tell you why you can not delete it.